# Stripe error (react payment processing with stripe)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, stripe-payments

Ok so this is a big one. I am creating a full stack amazon clone and I am currently working on payment processing with stripe. I am going to show you the code.
So this is the file where you are supposed to enter your card details

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useStateValue } from "../StateProvider";
import CheckoutProduct from "./CheckoutProduct";
import "./Payment.css";
import FlipMove from "react-flip-move";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { useElements, useStripe, CardElement } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import CurrencyFormat from "react-currency-format";
import { getBasketTotal } from "../reducer";
import axios from "../axios";

function Payment() {
  const [{ user, basket }, dispatch] = useStateValue();

  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();
  const history = useHistory();

  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
  const [succeeded, setSucceeded] = useState(false);
  const [processing, setProcessing] = useState("");
  const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getClientSecret = async () => {
      const responce = await axios({
        method: "post",
        url: `/payments/create?total=${getBasketTotal(basket) * 100}`,
      });
      setClientSecret(responce.data.clientSecret);
    };
    getClientSecret();
  }, [basket]);

  console.log("THE SECRET IS >>> ", clientSecret);

  const submitHandler = async (e) => {
    //stripe magic
    e.preventDefault();
    setProcessing(true);

    const payload = await stripe
      .confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
        payment_method: {
          card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
        },
      })
      .then(({ paymentIntent }) => {
        //paymentIntent = payment confirmation
        setSucceeded(true);
        setError(null);
        setProcessing(false);

        history.replace("/orders");
      });
  };

  const changeHandler = (e) => {
    //stripe magic
    setDisabled(e.empty);
    setError(e.error ? e.error.message : "");
  };

  return (
    <div className="payment">
      <div className="payment__container">
        <h1>
          Checkout(<Link to="/checkout">{basket?.length} items</Link>)
        </h1>

        <div className="payment__section">
          <div className="payment__title">
            <h3>Delivery Address</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="payment__address">
            <p>{user?.email}</p>
            <p>123 React Lane</p>
            <p>Los Angeles, CA</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="payment__section">
          <div className="payment__title">
            <h3>Review items and delivery</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="payment__items">
            <FlipMove>
              {basket.map((item) => (
                <div>
                  <CheckoutProduct
                    id={item.id}
                    title={item.title}
                    image={item.image}
                    price={item.price}
                    rating={item.rating}
                  />
                </div>
              ))}
            </FlipMove>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="payment__section">
          <div className="payment__title">
            <h3>Payment Method</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="payment__details">
            <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
              <CardElement onChange={changeHandler} />

              <div className="payment__priceContainer">
                <CurrencyFormat
                  renderText={(value) => (
                    <>
                      <h3>Order Total: {value}</h3>
                    </>
                  )}
                  decimalScale={2}
                  value={getBasketTotal(basket)}
                  displayType={"text"}
                  thousandSeperator={true}
                  prefix={"$"}
                />
                <button disabled={processing || disabled || succeeded}>
                  <span>{processing ? <p>Processing</p> : "Buy Now"}</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              {error && <div>{error}</div>}
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Payment;
```

This is the axios file:

```
import axios from "axios";

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:5001/clone-f805e/us-central1/api",
});

export default instance;
```

and here is my cloud function:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const stripe = require("stripe")(
  "not showing this ;)"
);

// API

// - App config
const app = express();

// - Middlewares
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
app.use(express.json());

// - API routes
app.get("/", (request, responce) => responce.status(200).send("hello world"));

app.post("/payments/create", async (request, responce) => {
  const total = request.query.total;

  console.log("Payment Request Received >>> ", total);

  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: total,
    currency: "usd",
  });
  // OK - Created
  responce.status(201).send({
    clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
  });
});

// - Listen command
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);

// Example endpoint
// http://localhost:5001/clone-f805e/us-central1/api
```

It says that I pass in `true` as a client secret, so the problem is that client secret is not getting updated in the first file. But I can't seem to figure out why. Here is the error in detail:

```
IntegrationError: Invalid value for stripe.confirmCardPayment intent secret: value should be a client_secret string. You specified: true.
```

If you need any imore information feel free to ask.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: First, I would recommend not setting the default state of the clientSecret to `true`. In general, when defining state it's a good idea to keep as true to a single type as possible. For a nilable type like this one I would set the default state to either null or undefined, and stick to that convention throughout your codebase. Second, you want to ensure that the checkout submit button is disabled unless a client-secret is available, which should make it impossible for the submit handler to be called unless the client secret exists, thereby fixing this issue.

Comment: I have updated the code so the button is disabled as long as the client secret is null (it is now null as default), but now the button just simply never activates... This is the button code now : `disabled={ processing || disabled || succeeded || clientSecret === null}`

Comment: Okay, perfect, so now at least you know that the issue is related to how you're requesting the client secret. If you open the network tab do you see any requests made out to `/payments/create?total=`, and if so, what does the response look like?

Comment: No, if Im reading this corretly I don't see any requests going out to that

Comment: Okay nevermind, so I am console logging out the client secret and now it is actually working. I don't know why, but I guess it was because I restarted the app. Anyways, thank ou very much for your help!

Comment: So on the stripe dashboard the payment is market as "uncompleted" and in the inspector console some requests are shown as "failed" I don't know if that is going to be a problem for what I want to do